# Determine datetime format from string

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, casting

Suppose I have some strings that contain arbitrary date & time information, e.g. `'2020-01-01T10:00:10.200', '2020-01-01 10:00', '2020-Jan-01'`, etc.

It is relatively straight forward to ensure that each string indeed contains such information by attempting to cast it into a `datetime` object:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

def is_datetime(mystring):
    try: 
        parse(mystring)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

It is also easy to convert the string into a `datetime` object *if the datetime format is known*:

```
import datetime
dt_1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-01-01T10:00:10.200', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
dt_2 = datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-01-01 10:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
dt_3 = datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-Jan-01', '%Y-%b-%d')
```

However, is there a way to determine the **datetime format from a given datetime string?** For example:

```
get_dt_format('2020-01-01T10:00:10.200') # should return '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'
get_dt_format('2020-01-01 10:00') # should return '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
get_dt_format('2020-Jan-01') # should return '%Y-%b-%d'
```

I managed to do this by checking each string against a collection of possible datetime formats until there is a match, but is there a better & more efficient way to do it?

Simplified current solution:

```
def _try_format(mystring, dt_format):
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(mystring, dt_format)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


def get_dt_format(mystring):
    possible_formats = ['%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', '%Y-%b-%d'] # and many others
    for possible_format in possible_formats:
        if _try_format(mystring, possible_format):
            return possible_format
    return 'Cannot determine format for ' + mystring
```

Thanks!

Comment: You may just find the cheaper between a regex and try to parse to date

Comment: Also have a look at `dateutil.parser.parse`.

Comment: How can you tell whether 01-01-2020, for example, is day-month-year or month-day-year?

Comment: @Roy2012 for more than 1 possible matches, it would peak one and inform the user (or just peak the first match for simplicity).

Comment: Check this library https://github.com/jeffreystarr/dateinfer for a starting point if you really want to implement. With python3 the import fails so use [this](https://github.com/jeffreystarr/dateinfer/issues/8) to fix if you want

Comment: Why are you trying to optimize this, is it too slow, do you know?

Comment: @martineau The current solution requires that all possible datetime formats are hardcoded and there are simply too many of them; especially if we include different separators e.g. `%Y/%m/%d` in addition to `%Y-%m-%d`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been looking at this problem as well, the best solution I could find was [py-dateinfer](https://pypi.org/project/py-dateinfer/) (someone suggested the predecessor of this library in the comments as well).

From the docs:

```
>>> import dateinfer
>>> dateinfer.infer(['Mon Jan 13 09:52:52 MST 2014', 'Tue Jan 21 15:30:00 EST 2014'])
'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex module if you want. I think your method is a bit tough because you have to write all possibilities.

For example if you want to catch a date like 2020-Jan-01 00:00

```
import re
date=2020-Jan-01 00:00

re.finditer(r"20\d\d-[a-z]{3}-[0123]\d \d\d:\d\d",date)
```

It will find all matches which fit to that pattern. That example pattern is not specific to a date, ie, it can also match 2020-abc-39 99:99 but you can find greater patterns. Or you can use %Y %M keys to find it.

**Or i have another solution:**

```
from itertools import permutations
import datetime
dates_str="20-Jan-2020 2000/May/06 11-Feb-2006 Mar-20-2013 We have an example about the date finding. You can write anything to here: 20/Jul/2020"

year_full="%Y"
month_abb="%b"
p_day="%d"      #1

for s_date in dates_str.split(" "):   #2
  for i in permutations([p_day,month_abb,year_full]):   #3
    for c in " -/.":   #4
      try:
        if datetime.datetime.strptime(s_date,f"{c}".join(list(i))):
          print(datetime.datetime.strptime(s_date,f"{c}".join(list(i))),"We found a date")
          break
      except:
        pass
```

Let me explain that code...

**#1**
I wrote keys which means year, month and date in date module. If you want, you can write some other keys for searching.

**#2**
Here we get all words from the string. For this code, term "word" means that characters which are separated by a whitespace (" ")

**#3**
That for loop is important. Here, we try all patterns which mean some date info, for all words. That generator contains these items: ('%d', '%b', '%Y'), ('%d', '%Y', '%b'), ('%b', '%d', '%Y'), ('%b', '%Y', '%d'), ('%Y', '%d', '%b'), ('%Y', '%b', '%d')

**#4**
You want the all possibilities about dates so we need some specifications. A date may have ".", "-", "/" or " " between numbers or any position: 20 Jan 2020 or 20/Jan/2020.

For catch these dates, i used a f-string in the function *join*.
At the end, code can catch dates which contains "/", "-" or " " in any pattern. We have 24 patterns and I want to write these patterns:

'%d %b %Y', '%d-%b-%Y', '%d/%b/%Y', '%d.%b.%Y',

'%d %Y %b', '%d-%Y-%b', '%d/%Y/%b', '%d.%Y.%b',

'%b %d %Y', '%b-%d-%Y', '%b/%d/%Y', '%b.%d.%Y',

'%b %Y %d', '%b-%Y-%d', '%b/%Y/%d', '%b.%Y.%d',

'%Y %d %b', '%Y-%d-%b', '%Y/%d/%b', '%Y.%d.%b',

'%Y %b %d', '%Y-%b-%d', '%Y/%b/%d', '%Y.%b.%d'

But this code has some problems:

1-If a date has a whitespace like 05 Jan 2012, i am not sure that this code will find it. Because we separate string from whitespaces.

2-I used generators for saving RAM but a small problem is the time. For very long strings, it can take a while because we **try every pattern for each word.**

3-I could not write these loops in a single line because we need a try/except block but this block is not writable in a line.

If you find the usage of keys "%Y", "%d" in regex for searching a date, please inform me...

Comment: Yes but the format can be anything. The idea is to find the datetime format without knowing what it looks like.